# jQuery how to get div element value from radio button and assign value to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I need to get the selected radio button value (123,456,789) and assign it to `valueee` div element? I used `document.getElementsById`, but couldn't get what I need.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Radio Button Selection</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#radio_submit").click(function(e) {
        var checked_option_radio = document.getElementsByName("deff").value;
        if (checked_option_radio === undefined) {
          alert('Please select options!');
        } else {
          alert("inside else");
          $('#valueee').html(checked_option_radio);

        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myform">
    <div>Choose option:</div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="user_options" />
    </div>
    <div name="deff" id="val1">123</div>
    <span>CSS</span>
    <br></br>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="user_options" />
    </div>
    <div name="deff" id="val2">456</div>
    <span>html</span>
    <br></br>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="user_options" />
    </div>
    <div name="deff" id="val3">678</div>
    <span>jquery</span>
    <br></br>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="user_options" />
    </div>
    <div name="deff" id="val4">675</div>
    <span>JS</span>
    <br></br>


    <div><button id="radio_submit" type="button">Show Selected Radio</button></div>
  </form>
  <div id="valueee"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#radio_submit").click(function (e) {
        var checked_option_radio = $("input[name=user_options]:checked").val();
    });
});
```

#### Full Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#radio_submit").click(function (e) {
     var checked_option_radio = $("input[name=user_options]:checked").val();
     if(checked_option_radio===undefined){
          alert('Please select options!');
     }else{
          alert("inside else");
          $('#valueee').html(checked_option_radio);  
     }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
<div>Choose option:</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options" value="456"/>
</div>
<div name="deff" id="val1" x>123</div>
<span>CSS</span>
<br></br>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options" value="456" /> 
</div>
<div name="deff" id="val2" >456</div>
<span>html</span>
<br></br>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options" value="678" /> 
</div>
<div name="deff" id="val3" >678</div>
<span>jquery</span>
<br></br>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options" value="675" />
</div>
<div name="deff" id="val4" >675</div>
<span>JS</span>
<br></br>


<div><button id="radio_submit" type="button">Show Selected Radio</button></div>
</form>
<div id="valueee"></div>
```

---

#### Check <kbd>[**jsFiddl**e](http://jsfiddle.net/ebLdawh6/)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry! Actually, you have manually set the value in radio button field. But, My requirement is inside div name ="deff", all values are get from backend. I need to validations for that

Comment: as per my knowledge you add seprate div for input base on selection selected input div next div value you want to get, am i right.

Comment: Absolutely right. Separate div for radio button, verbiage and specific value

Comment: okay as per your requirement i added jsfiddle link bottom of my answer. you can check it.

Comment: you welcome, but i suggest you do not use separate `div`. thanks

Comment: If I am using one text box and 3 div, how can I set the entered value in that div? Like this..http://jsfiddle.net/ebLdawh6/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64760/discussion-between-user1153551-and-uidesigner).

Answer (score 1):

```
I am adding a class for selected radio button parent div,based on the class I am getting the next div text and printing in the desired place using Jquery.
```

Rename the name=deff to class=deff.

```
    $("#radio_submit").click(function (e) {
    var checked_option_radio = $(this).closest('form').find('div').hasClass('selected');
    if(checked_option_radio) {
        var hello = $('.selected').next('.deff').text();
        $('#valueee').html(hello);
    } else {
        alert('nothing selected');
        var hello2 = "no radio button is selected"
        $('#valueee').html(hello2);
    }
 });
$('input').on('click',function(){
    if (!$("input").is(':checked')) {
                              $(this).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
             $(this).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
});


<form id="myform">
<div>Choose option:</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options" />
</div>
<div class="deff" id="val1">123</div>
<span>CSS</span>
<br></br>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options"  /> 
</div>
<div class="deff" id="val2">456</div>
<span>html</span>
<br></br>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options"  /> 
</div>
<div class="deff" id="val3">678</div>
<span>jquery</span>
<br></br>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="user_options" />
</div>
<div class="deff" id="val4">675</div>
<span>JS</span>
<br></br>


<div><button id="radio_submit" type="button">Show Selected Radio</button></div>
</form>
<div id="valueee"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/xeb9hoyr/2/

Here is the updated code to get input value

```
var check_div = $('.selected').next().is('div');
        var check_input = $('.selected').next().is('input');
        var div_value = $('.selected').next('.deff').text();
        var input_value = $('.selected').next('input').val();
        if(check_div){     
            $('#valueee').html(div_value);
        }
        if(check_input){
         $('#valueee').html(input_value);    
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/xeb9hoyr/9/

Comment: Appreciate your work! Can you look into this? http://jsfiddle.net/xeb9hoyr/4/  If I use text box, how can I get the keyup value as like div

Answer (score -1):

since you have the jquery library implemented use

```
 $('#divid').val(somevalue);
```

Comment: I am getting undefined in alert..how can I set the value?

Comment: var stringvalue= "asdasdasdasd"; $('#divid').val(stringvalue); where divid is the ID="" in your div tag